# predict.rma() function in metafor to meta-analyse across moderators

Tags: r, predict, metafor

I am using metafor to run a multivariate meta-analysis. I want to predict effects of new moderators but for one of the moderators I do not want to input a value itself, but I want the predict function to meta-analyse that moderator (in the example below this is `grade`)

I am using here the toy dataset `dat.bangertdrowns2004`.

```
# load metafor package
library(metafor)
dat <- dat.bangertdrowns2004

# fit model
res <- rma.mv(yi, vi, mods = ~ grade + length + pers - 1, random = ~ 1 | ni,  data=dat)
res

# predict
gridpred <- expand.grid(length=4:10, pers=1)
pred.res <- predict.rma(object = res , newmods = as.matrix(gridpred))
```

When I run this code I get an error as it mentions that I need to input a value for `grade`.

```
Error in predict.rma(object = res, newmods = as.matrix(gridpred)) : 
  Argument 'newmods' does not specify values for this variable: grade
```

Is there a way of using predict.rma() to meta-analyse grade across `length=4:10` and `pers=1`?

Comment: You might be thinking of something like this: https://www.metafor-project.org/doku.php/tips:computing_adjusted_effects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are indeed looking for such 'adjusted means/estimates', then one would hold the value of `grade` constant at its mean. So the syntax would be:

```
gridpred <- expand.grid(length=4:10, pers=1, grade=colMeans(model.matrix(res))["grade"])
pred.res <- predict.rma(object = res , newmods = as.matrix(gridpred))
pred.res
```

If you want to use `emmeans`, then you would use:

```
library(emmeans)
sav <- emmprep(res, at=list(pers=1, length=4:10))
emmeans(sav, specs="1", by=c("pers","length"))
```

Comment: Great, thanks! 
And what if I want to do the same but using a categorical indicator (3 or more levels)? As it would not be possible to take the mean...

Comment: This is directly addressed on the website I linked to. Essentially, one can take the mean of the dummy variables that represent such a factor.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the tip, Wolfgang!
I have adapted the code based on the link you sent (https://www.metafor-project.org/doku.php/tips:computing_adjusted_effects), on the section "Addendum: Using the emmeans Package".

```r
for (l in 4:10){
  sav <- emmprep(res, at=list(length=l, pers=1, grade=c(1:4)))
  emm <- emmeans(sav, specs="1", type="response", weights="proportional")
  print(emm)
}
```

Now this gives the average across all grades for each length value, is this what you meant?